# Filtering GridView rows not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've written some code in the Page_PreRender event that gets the value of a DropDownList control and then performs some conditional logic. Problem is, the logic must not be very good.

The first If.. Then.. Else.. structure is working fine, however, if the selectedItem is **not** "Todos" (portuguese for "all") all the rows' visibility will be set to false. The issue seems to arise when the `If SelectedItem <> "Todos" Then` condition is met.

So, every option in the DropDownList aside from "Todos" sets the visibility of all rows to False instead of setting the visibility of the ones that don't match the SelectedItem to False.

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    'Getting the selected item
    Dim SelectedItem As String = CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text
    If SelectedItem <> "Todos" Then
        'This is the part where the issue seems to be located.                        
        For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            'Get the Text value 
            Dim depar As String = Row.Cells(3).Text
            'If its different from the SelectedItem then the row's visible property should be set to false, if it's a match, set it to true.

            If depar <> SelectedItem Then
                Row.Visible = False
            ElseIf depar = SelectedItem Then
                Row.Visible = True
            End If
        Next
        'If "Todos" was selected, all rows should be visible
    ElseIf SelectedItem = "Todos" Then
        'Make all rows visible
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            row.Visible = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Code of GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="20" Width="100%"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#CType(Container, GridViewRow).DataItem("IdPedido") %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command">Ver</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="40px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Observacoes" HeaderText="Assunto" SortExpression="Observacoes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NomeHotel" HeaderText="Hotel" SortExpression="NomeHotel" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Departamento" SortExpression="NomeDepartamento">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    Departamento<br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="NomeDepartamento" DataValueField="IdDepartamento" AutoPostBack="True" OnLoad="DropDownList1_Load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem>Todos</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EnotelSuporteConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [NomeDepartamento], [IdDepartamento] FROM [Departamentos]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                </HeaderTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NomeDepartamento") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NomeDepartamento") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataPedido" HeaderText="Data" DataFormatString = "{0:dd, MMM yyyy}" SortExpression="DataPedido" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataFinalizado" HeaderText="Finalizado a" DataFormatString = "{0:dd, MMM yyyy}" SortExpression="DataFinalizado" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="Nome" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Estado" HeaderText="Estado" SortExpression="Estado" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdPedido" HeaderText="IdPedido" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IdPedido" Visible="False" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Every option in the DropDownList aside from "Todos" sets the visibility of all rows to False instead of setting the visibility of the ones that don't match the SelectedItem to False.

Comment: The issue remains even when using those.

Comment: I've tried it, but I can't check the value of `depar` or `Row.Cells(3).Text` while debugging for some unknown reason. This makes me think the issue is that I'm not properly getting the value of `Row.Cells(3).Text`, don't know what's wrong with it though.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I was setting the breakpoint outside of the scope of `depar` and Row.cells(3).text, `depar` is empty and the same goes for `Row.Cells(3).Text`.

Comment: Maybe in the Page_PreRender event the text of the cells isn't yet defined?   I say this because I'm sure there's text in all of the cells.

Comment: Added the code for the GridView.

Comment: The `Departamento` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe problem in your `Row.Cells(3).Text`  is that you are defining the `ItemTemplate` in your `gridview` with `Label` and to get the `ItemTemplates` value you have to first find the control and then get the value from that control. 
If you want the value of the label then use the following code to get the value,

```
Label label = (Label)Row.Cells(3).FindControl("Label1");
if(label != null)
   string depar = label.Text;
```

**NOTE**
Code is in the c# you might want to convert it to the VB.